# Google Play Console Warning : Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NO_APKS

Tags: android, react-native, build, google-play-console

I've just updated my React-Native app and got this error message at *Google Play Console* when I tried to make another **internal test version**.

> Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NO_APKS

[image]

The latest version was uploaded with no trouble and there were only few changes in this version. Nothing to doubt. Sorry for such little information.

Has anyone got in trouble with this error message when trying to upload the newly updated app on Google Play Console?

Comment: Have you tried to reupload apk/aab. I just solved my problem with creating new scenario. It seems that my file is null

Comment: Yes. I'd removed 'android > .gradle' directory and rebuilt it and created aab file for like several times but still seeing the same error message :(

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I had made several value-langs direcories to set multiligual app titles under the 'app>src>main>res' directory.  
Now I removed them and created new aab file and the error has gone. 

I think there should be only one values directory or something. But quite not sure. 
Thank you for your comment. :)  @NandaZ

Answer (score 34):

I had a similar kind of issue. what I got was 
"Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_MISSING_COUNTRY_PRICES"

I fixed it by editing the App pricing for the app. Reduced the price -> saved it and then changed it back to the old price. It was some weird issue with the playstore!

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: Worked for me too! In my case the error message was "Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_COUNTRY_PRICE_BAD_ROUNDING" (probably a wrong float number in my App prices...). Changed my App price -> Saved it -> Problem fixed!

Comment: The same solution fixed mine too!

Comment: Thank you ! This fixed it for me too

Answer (score 12):

Just faced this exact issue. If you have a pricing template setup, follow Dipu's solution. If not, just go to App Pricing. Then, click on `Edit Price` then click on `Update Exchange Rates`. Then `Save`.
Now go back to releases and click on review and release.
That's it! The problem should be solved.

Answer (score 6):

Some countries has been added or removed or their policies have been changed for pricing that is why the error shown.

Just edit price and click on "update exchange rates" and apply changes

Answer (score 5):

Got same problem...here is how i fixed it...

Just go to the pricing template => go in your linked template to your game/app => click on edit price => click on update exchange rate

After this that error message will not appear...

If error still appear change price a little click on update exchange rate and save...

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I simply temporarily changed the pricing template to a new one:
Monetize > Products > App pricing > Change pricing template

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the "Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_MISSING_COUNTRY_PRICES" problem.

I fixed it by editing the App pricing and just clicking the "Update exchange" button. After that, just save and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Change SDK Version as per below in **build.gradle(app)**

```
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
```

And make again with signed APK and upload on Playstore and It's worked for me.